# How do you transfer a domain with BlueHost?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, domain-registration, bluehost

I have a domain purchased. I have a website without a domain that I can view with the IP address. I need to point the website to the domain. It is hosted with BlueHost but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do it?

For what it is worth I have installed WordPress successfully and have access to the Admin Panel with the ip address + `/wp-admin` suffix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, this does not require "transferring a domain".

Go to where DNS is hosted (the nameservers tell you that) and in DNS you need to add (or edit) an `A Record` that points to the IP address of the bluehost server.